# C reading in from a vertical line character delimited file

Tags: c++, file-io, delimiter, scanf, csv

new to C and trying to read in a text file, "stocks", delimited with vertical line '|' characters. Aim is to open the file which is has a string and float value on each line, in the format:

```
TOM|149.62
JIM|23.25
```

I have read other posts about commas, colon and tab delimited files, but the "scanset" suggestion applied here as a `[^|]` between the `%s` and `%f` doesn't seem to work. I seem to have managed to store the first character of the string at least now, but the float value saved is nonsense. This will later be writing to the arrays declared after the file but the basic case of displaying the string and float value for each line means I can continue on my own. Appreciate any help you can give me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

// TOM|149.62
// JIM|23.25


int main()
{
    FILE *stocks;

    char *stock_Tickers[100];
    float stock_Prices[100];

    if ((stocks = fopen("Stocks.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char tempchar;
    float tempfloat;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (stock_Tickers); i++)
    {
        if (feof(stocks))
        {
            break;
        }
        fscanf(stocks, "%s[^|]%f\n",&tempchar,&tempfloat);
        cout << tempchar << " " << tempfloat;
        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Update: @Michel Billaud Apologies, but I have one last error here. Your method worked perfectly, but when I try it on this slight variant it starts printing rubbish on the last floating point and breaks on subsequent loops. Looked at the local variables and the last array just isn't updating. I think it has to do with the new line, as when I change the float for an integer it still doesn't work. Can you see what I might be doing wrong as it seems the same format to me? Format this time is `Ryan|B|IBM|100|176.10`. All files are read in after this...Thanks.

```
FILE *trades;
    // Ryan|B|IBM|100|176.10    
    // Ryan|S|IBM|50|177.10

    char trade_User[100][20];
    char trade_Type[100];
    char trade_Tickers[100][4];
    int trade_Quantity[100];
    float trade_Prices[100];
    int trade_Count = 0;

    if ((trades = fopen("Trades.txt","r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(trade_Tickers); i++)
    {
        if (feof(trades))
        {
            break;
        }
    fscanf(trades, "%19[^|]|%1[^|]|%4[^|]|%d[^|]|%f\n", 
        &trade_User[i], &trade_Type[i], &trade_Tickers[i], &trade_Quantity[i], &trade_Prices[i]);
    printf("%s %c %s %d %f\n", 
        trade_User[i], trade_Type[i], trade_Tickers[i], trade_Quantity[i], trade_Prices[i]);
    trade_Count++;
}
```

Comment: `char tempchar;` --> `char tempchar[32];`.. `fscanf(stocks, "%31[^|]|%f\n",tempchar,&tempfloat);`

Comment: C or C++? You say C, but your code is obviously in C++.

Comment: Also, in C++, you should use `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>`. The headers you use are only for C.

Comment: It is supposed to all be in C, hence the C headers. The code is in line with my "Teach yourself C" textbook... I don't know what to say :s

Comment: And thank you very much BluePixy, that has worked perfectly for what I needed.

Comment: You are using a C++ compiler, with C++ output (`cout` instead of `printf()`), so you should consider learning C++ file IO, such as `std::ifstream`, `std;;getline()`, and `std;istringstream`.

Comment: appreciated, but the project has to be in C so have edited back to regular printf()

Comment: @Rysz You can't use `<iostream>`, `cout`, or the stream operator `<<` in C. You have to use `printf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** when trying to use a problematic feature, do it in a small separate program. So you won't take the risk to draw wrong conclusions because of another unrelated issue.

```
// just playing with |-separated fields

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char line[]="TOM|1234.56";
    char name[20];
    float value;
    sscanf(line, "%[^|]|%f", name,  &value);
    printf("name = %s, value = %f\n", name, value);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way: seems you're using the C++ compiler (because of "using namespace std").

Comment: Thanks will keep in mind. Kept the std in from my first Visual Studio project test which was a C++ one and copied over. Thanks for pointing out.